# Hide edit menu ellipsis in Sharepoint 2013 Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, edit, ecb-menu

I have a Document Library in Sharepoint 2013 with a Name (linked to document with edit menu) column which has an edit menu ellipsis. I need to keep this column but hide the ellipsis (this is because, for some reason, the icon will only show a hover preview panel if I have this type of Name column). I have an edit menu ellipsis on another column and need to keep that one so I need target the ellipsis just in the Name column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use developer tool to check the element attribute/class to hide it.

For example:

[image]

```
<style>
a[title="Open Menu"]{
display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

Or hide parent div.

```
<style>
div.ms-list-itemLink{
display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Lee_MSFT but is there a way of targeting a singular column? Like I said, I have 2 columns with the ellipsis but only want to remove them from one of the columns.

Comment: Try to check nth-child(odd)/nth-child(even)  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp